# How do i show only 2 divs at a time onclick

Tags: jquery, html

I have four divs each of which have an image. All the images are hidden initially and will be displayed on click. I want only maximum of two images to be displayed at a time and if a third image is clicked that should be blocked. Please help. I need to use bind and unbind probably.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.outline img').hide().closest('div').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('img',this).toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<div class="outline">
    <div id="one"><a href="#"><img id="11" src="1.png"></a></div>
    <div id="two"><img  id ="12" src="2.png"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <div id="three"><img id="21" src="2.png"></div>
    <div id="four"><img id="22" src="1.png"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.outline img').hide().closest('div').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("img",this).is(":visible")) {
            $('img',this).toggle();
        }
        else if($('img:hidden').length > 2) {
            $('img',this).toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:hidden` instead of `hide` in this context

```
$('.outline img:hidden').parent().click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('img',this).toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for example

```
var toggled = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.outline img').hide().closest('div').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('img',this).hasClass("toggle")){
      $('img',this).removeClass("toggle").toggle();
      var toggled--;
    } else {
      if (toggled < 2) {
      $('img',this).addClass("toggle").toggle();
      var toggled++;
    }
    $('img',this).toggle();
});
});
```

It wil keep track how many are toggled in the toggled var, and when you toggle it, you'll add the show class, if there are 2 open you can't open others. Closing does a minus 1 to the toggled var. So it should work this way, and you have some data/classes to check howmany and which are open.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's what you need. Your question and code seems little messy but I've tried hard to get it right:

```
$(function() {
    var outline = $('.outline');

    outline.find('img').closest('div').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var that = $(this);

        if (that.parents('.three').length > 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (outline.find('img:visible').length >= 2) {
            return false;
        }

        that.show();
    });
});
```